# Are WGSI and non-WSGI Django apps designed/written differently?

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'm new to Python and Django.

This is a very basic question, but I can't find a straight answer:

When writing my Django app, do I have to design the app itself differently if it's going to support WSGI?

In other words, is WSGI purely a *deployment* decision, or does the app itself have to support WSGI by design? Can I just write an app without thinking about whether it's WSGI or not and flip a WSGI switch later on, or does WSGI stuff go deeper?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Because there is no such thing as a non-WSGI Django app. Django is a WSGI app, because it supports the WSGI protocol, meaning you can use any standards-compliant WSGI *server* to host your Django app.

So yes, WSGI is a deployment decision.

---

Someone might point out that Django can also be hosted using the [ASGI Channels server](https://channels.readthedocs.io/), but the Django integration is basically an ASGI-to-WSGI adapter. Django itself is still being deployed driven the same way as a WSGI server would, and the way you develop your Django app doesn't change.